# Are images downloaded from URL saved in cache?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm wondering if the images that are downloaded using this code:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *uiImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage);
```

are cached? Because I want every time that I execute the above code it just downloads the image and not take the cache.

Because when you do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
[data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

The file will be cached and when you execute the same code it will take the cache instead of taking the data from the link.
Even if you remove the file from the directory it still uses the cache.

Comment: It's worth doing a search before posting a question to avoid creating dupes.

Answer (score -1):

Those methods do not cache the file. I'd recommend using a library such as [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to achieve that.

Comment: The second code does cache since I need to add ?t="randomNumber" to the link otherwise it doesn't update the text from the link